# Construction of function

Tags: functions

I'm trying to construct a function $ f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ which has exactly 3 limit points. I'm stuck and can't think of one. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "has exactly limit in 3 points"?  Do you mean limit points instead?

Comment: @dmtri yes, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

$f(x) = 1/x$ for $x \in (0,+\infty)$ and $f(x) = -1/x$ for $x\in (-\infty,0)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Dirichlet's function

$D(x)=\begin{cases}
  1,  & \text{for x rational} \text{,}\\
  0, & \text{for x irrational} \text{.}
\end{cases}$

defined for all real x, has no limit at any point.

I would say, function $f(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\cdot D(x)$ has limits:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to1}=0, \quad\lim_{x\to2}=0, \quad \lim_{x\to3}=0 \quad, $ no other limits.

Similarly, a function can be defined with an arbitrary number of limits.

I remembered constructing a function, I could not possibly deduce it.